# How to add custom transition to react-bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to replace the default slide in from the top/bottom transition of a `<Modal>` with custom one. The docs say that I can set the `transition` prop with `react-transition-group@2.0.0 <Transition/>` but I couldn't figure out what to do exactly.
The way I understand it is that I can create a `<Transition>` component like this:

```
const Fade = () => (
  <CSSTransition in={true} appear={true} classNames="fade" timeout={1000} />
);
```

and set that to the `transition` prop like so:

```
<Button variant="light" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open Modal</Button>
<Modal show={isOpen} onHide={() => setIsOpen(false)} animation={false} transition={Fade}>
...
</Modal>
```

but it didn't work. I also tried

```
const transition = <CSSTransition in={true} appear={true} classNames="fade" timeout={1000} />
...
<Button variant="light" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open Modal</Button>
<Modal show={isOpen} onHide={() => setIsOpen(false)} animation={false} transition={transition}>
...
</Modal>
```

but it also didn't work.
Here is the **scss** (It's not the transition I want but just a simple one for testing. It works with other components by wrapping them in `<CSSTransition>` element)

```scss
.fade {
    &-appear {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        &-active {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 600ms linear;
        }
    }
    &-enter {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        &-active {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 600ms linear;
        }
    }
    &-exit {
        opacity: 1;
        &-active {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 600ms linear;
        }
    }
}
```

I use `"react-bootstrap": "^1.6.6"` and `"bootstrap": "^4.5.0"`

Comment: just guessing here but maybe in your fade component add children? ```const Fade = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <CSSTransition in={true} appear={true} classNames="fade" timeout={1000} >{children}</CSSTransition>
);```

Comment: @Breezer Didn't work. I guess this prop only work with other components and you can't change it on a Modal. I even tried setting `dialogClassName="animationDialog"` and forcing animation through CSS (`.animationDialog { transform: translateX(20px) !important; transition: transform 3s ease-in !important; }``) but it just disabled the animations all together.

Comment: @FieryRider did you manage to resolve this one? I'm having the same question